# Widget not updating in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method called getData for a stateful widget

```
void getData() async{
var bitCoinPrice1 = (await coinData.getPriceData('BTC$selectedCurrency')).toStringAsFixed(2);
bitCoinPrice = bitCoinPrice1;
}
```

I am calling this method inside a drop down change event

```
  onChanged: (String newValue) {
    setState(
      () {
        selectedCurrency = newValue;
        print("Selected currency changed to $selectedCurrency");
        getData();
      },
    );
  }
```

Unless I enclose the contents in getData in another setState(), the value of bitcoinPrice doesn't reflect in the widget. My questions is : If call to getData() is already inside setState(), why does it require to have another setState() call inside getData() to update the widget?

Comment: you are using await in getData method, so it takes time to complete process because of that you require setState over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getData` is `async`, so the execution of the body for `setState` terminates immediately, updating the state before the `async` result is delivered.
Since `setState` doesn't allow an `async` body you have to do things differently.

Given the code you've provided, you could do something like this:

```
onChanged: (String newValue) {
    selectedCurrency = newValue;
    print("Selected currency changed to $selectedCurrency");
    getData();
}
```

and update the `getData` code like this:

```
void getData() async{
  var bitCoinPrice1 = (await coinData.getPriceData('BTC$selectedCurrency')).toStringAsFixed(2);
  setState({
    bitCoinPrice = bitCoinPrice1;
  });
}
```

This way the `setState` will be called after the `await`-ed operation is done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need another setState() inside getData() function, because can take more time to conclude getPriceData function (async method). After

```
bitCoinPrice = bitCoinPrice1;
```

You need to call setState to refresh widgets.